# Do chainsaw gloves protect your hands from the blade of a jigsaw?

Tags: safety, jigsaw

I know that gloves of any kind do not protect a woodworker against a circular saw, on the contrary they can make matters worse. However, when using a jigsaw, like the one in the picture, do chainsaw gloves, or of a different type, protect the hands and fingers of the worker from the blade? I have read that the jigsaw is one of the least dangerous power tools for cutting wood and other materials and I intend to buy one but I never used any power tool for cutting. I want to utilize it especially **for making long straight cuts in plywood** up to 1/2 inch thick and also for cutting framing studs 2 x 4 inch (which I understand are in fact 1.5 x 3.5 inch). Sometimes, but rarely, I have to cut the stud along its longitudinal axis to make two thinner studs. I do not plan to use this tool too often. Maybe, twice a year.

[image]
[4.8 Amp Corded Variable Speed Orbital Jig Saw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-4-8-Amp-Corded-Variable-Speed-Orbital-Jig-Saw-JS481LG/205105611)

**[Video showing a chainsaw stopped by a special glove (Soft Touch Chainsaw Glove C-2000):](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBhor_4zIXk)**

Comment: I've owned a jigsaw for a few decades and never once was in a position to accidentally injure myself with a moving blade. I've accidentally triggered the power, but even then, no blade contact was made. I suspect you'll find that gloves are not necessary.

Comment: Agree that jigsaws are pretty benign. That said, I think it's better to learn good safety habits from the outset, rather than thinking that you've got gloves that'll protect you.

Comment: I'll add that a jigsaw is specifically designed to be good at cutting _curves_. This makes it not well suited for cutting _straight_ lines, _especially_ for someone who has never used power tools before. Circular saws _seem_ scary, and the _can_ remove fingers in the blink of an eye, but with appropriate care in their use (not bothering with magic chain saw gloves for a false sense of security) are very safe and are much better suited for straight cuts. Watch some YT videos on how to use a circular saw, have your "that looks dangerous" radar turned up to 15 and you'll pick up good tips.

Comment: Short answer to the question in the title, no, I don't think so. The way that chainsaw protection stuff generally works is that it is designed to jam the mechanism so thoroughly that it overcomes the power of the motor, swiftly and permanently. The same jamming mechanism doesn't apply to jigsaws. If you want to just protect your hands generally from rough, splintery wood and the possible occasional (very occasional) accidental touch against the blade (*even when not moving*) then basic leather work gloves seem like they'd be ideal.

Comment: *"for making long straight cuts in plywood "* Very much not the ideal tool for this! You **can** make straight cuts in ply and other wood with a jigsaw, but they are not purpose-built for this task and I'm sure you're going to find that achieving quality cuts — and maintaining them once you have your technique down pat — is going to be a source of frustration. The longer the cut the more the issue will raise its head.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has weighed in with a complete answer, I'll give it a shot.

Jigsaws are pretty benign as cutting tools. Except for the obvious issue of putting a body part close to the blade, the most common thing for a jigsaw seems to be a blade binding and the whole saw hopping up and down, which is bothersome and might thump a finger.

I'd suggest that you build habits around not having your hands in proximity to the blade, rather than getting a (possibly false) sense of security in the form of a protective glove. It might even be the case that having a glove makes you more likely to do something strange and dangerous. (YMMV.) Clamping a workpiece securely so you can concentrate on cutting, rather than holding and cutting is a good idea.

As mentioned by @FreeMan, the jigsaw isn't great for a long straight rip cut. Once in a blue moon isn't too bad, but if you find yourself needing this functionality regularly, a circular saw might be a good next step. At least find a jigsaw blade that's long enough to cut 1.5" and has relatively few teeth for easier ripping. (And a couple of rips might convince you to just buy the right size lumber to start with.)

Comment: I'll emphasize that a jig saw is **_not_** the tool you want for resawing ("cut the stud along its longitudinal axis to make two thinner studs"). If you're cutting on the 4" face, you'll be OK, but _will_ have a ragged cut (not straight). If you're trying to cut the 2" face, forgetaboutit! For resawing, you need a table saw or a band saw - find someone who owns one to help you with this or hit up your local lumber yard (not big-box store) and purchase lumber dimensioned to the size you need.